# How to Record & Filter Load Times for Web Ads in Different Browsers?

Tags: manual-testing, performance, load-testing

I need to be able to record advertisement load times for pretty much any website a client asks me to, on various browsers **(Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge, Safari)**, desktop browsers specifically.

*I've used the Developer tools in chrome before to monitor network performance and output to a HAR file.  I also have used several online tools/extensions to parse and view the HAR file data more easily.*

---

1. **How can I *specifically filter out Ads from the rest of the data*, and separate that data to present to a client?**
2. **Are there any cross browser tools that work just as well/better than
   Chrome/FF Dev tools to make data collection and presentation more
   efficient and consistent?**
3. **If there are no cross-browser tools that address all the needed browsers, which tools do I need to perform the same tasks on the various browsers?**

---

#### Chrome - ?

#### Firefox - ?

#### Internet Explorer - ?

#### Safari - ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for that. It works with any browser as this is just a proxy that allows you to capture and analyze web traffic. In order to see loading times in the session summary add the TTLB column to the session viewer. Fiddler provides multiple filtering options, for example, in case your adds are on dedicated host, you can set up filters to display traffic only from that host. Fiddler supports bunch of export formats including HAR, so you can continue using the same tools for reporting, also you can export captured data into csv\tsv with script\plugin or just by clicking `Copy -> Full Summary` and pasting copied data to Excel.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and informative reply.  I will give that a try.  I appreciate your help.